# infinite scrolling only loading first page in ie 7/8

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

Im using infinite scrolling on a website to load in content https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll , it works fine in all major browsers and even IE 9, but on ie 7/8 it only loads the first page and displays "no more content", when there are more pages to be loaded. Also there are no errors poping up either. I have looked at the demo on the devs website and that works fine in ie 7/8.

Anyone come across this?

I even came across this http://forum.jquery.com/topic/fix-jquery-ajax-errors-in-ie and tried it but I get the success message.

Using this code :

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ListView1_ctrl0_Ul1').infinitescroll({
    navSelector   : "#plist-Paging:last",
    nextSelector  : "#plist-Paging a:last",
    itemSelector  : ".ISProdContainerOuter",
    debug     : false,
    dataType    : 'html', 
    bufferPx     : 100
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Have you run the developer tools on IE 8 and see what the network traffic looks like?

Comment: What other code do you need to see?
in the network traffic I can see it calls to the next page, and starts load in the elements but then just stops.